# How to select optional components during FreeBSD 9.0 Install?

Tags: freebsd, system-installation

I am installing FreeBSD 9.0 on VMWare Player. In section 2.5.3 of the [installation guide](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/using-bsdinstall.html) it shows that one can choose which components to install. What keys on the keyboard do I need to use to (de)select those options?

I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: From the page itself:  "The bsdinstall menu system is controlled by the arrow keys, Enter, Tab, Space, and other keys". Do those work?

Comment: I used that as a reference, but I was following an instruction set from a professor which did not include that information. Thanks again.

Comment: Don't believe professors. The saying goes "Those who can do, do; those who can't, teach." [_Always_ look at the documentation for the exact same stuff you are messing around with. Professor's notes, webpages, comments here will probably all be outdated, faded memories, misunderstandings, or all three.]

Comment: @vonbrand To this man's credit, he works full time as the head of the infosec for the university's cyber infrastructure. He's an adjunct professor and it's a nighttime graduate class, but advice well taken.

Comment: @SeanBaskin, I was talking about me ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press <kbd>Space</kbd> to select an option